# sql query error #Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, error-handling, phpmyadmin

[image: This is the image MY QUERY AND TABLES/COLUMN I USED FOR THE QUERY]

```
Select heros.Nom,heros.Prenom
From (
    SELECT  ID_Heros, 
            COUNT(ID_ville) AS nmbr,
            (
                SELECT * 
                FROM etape 
                RIGHT JOIN participe ON etape.ID_Expedition= pqrticipe.ID_Expedition
            ) as sub1 
    GROUP BY ID_Heros 
    ORDER BY COUNT(ID_ville) LIMIT 1
) As sub2 
INNER JOIN heros On sub2.ID_Heros = heros.ID_Héros
```

**Questions :**
Query is used for :  *The most traveling hero (the most different cities crossed)*

## 1064 - Syntax error near 'GROUP BY ID_Heros ORDER BY COUNT (city_ID) LIMIT 1) As sub2

```
INNER JOIN hero 'at line 5
```

Why do i have this error ? (How can i fix it maybe)

**I think it's about the 2 count but i am not sure**

Comment: Add column to select which is on `group by` and `order by`

Comment: Hello , i still ahve the same error
GROUP BY ID_Heros ORDER BY COUNT(ID_ville) LIMIT 1)

Comment: Please copy the error message and paste it as part of the question. For me it is unreadable.

Comment: Hello , This is the *error*
`# 1064 - Syntax error near 'GROUP BY ID_Heros ORDER BY COUNT (city_ID) LIMIT 1) As sub2
    INNER JOIN hero 'at line 5`

Comment: any luck ? I am so stuck right now

Comment: The `sub2` query is missing a `FROM` clause.

Comment: MySql <> Sql Server.